# Domino AppDev Pack 1.0.1.3

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-appdev-pack

I used the make_certs.cmd from Domino App Dev Pack 1.0.12-2786, I have 3 questions.

1. why I didn't get the output ca.seq file.
2. The .pem file are convert by myself , should I use the serverkey.pem and servercrt.pem to import into the porton server.
3. Should I create the user called proton-server, app1, app2, iamclientforproton ?

   @echo off
   setlocal

   if "%OPENSSL_CONF%"=="" (
   echo OPENSSL_CONF is required for openSSL on Windows.
   exit /B 1
   )

   @REM CUSTOMIZE: Change the parameters here

   @REM The subject name of the root certificate.
   SET ROOT_SUBJECT=/O=Org/CN=OrgCA
   @REM The number of days the root certificate will be valid.
   SET ROOT_VALIDITY=3650
   @REM The password to create and access the root certificate.
   SET ROOT_PASSWORD=pass:xxxxxxxxxx
   @REM Number of days leaf certificate(s) will be valid.
   SET LEAF_VALIDITY=365
   @REM The password to create and access the leaf certificate(s).
   SET LEAF_PASSWORD=pass:xxxxxxxxxx

   call :create_root || exit /B 1

   @REM CUSTOMIZE: Change the list of certificates to create and their attributes.
   @REM Parameters to create_leaf: "file-name" "subject-name" "optional-subject-alternate-names"
   @REM call :create_leaf server "/O=Org/CN=admin" "DNS:serv.org.com" || exit /B 1
   call :create_leaf server "/O=Org/CN=proton-server" "DNS:domino1.serv.org.com" || exit /B 1
   call :create_leaf app1 "/O=Org/CN=app1" "" || exit /B 1
   call :create_leaf app2 "/O=Org/CN=app2" "" || exit /B 1
   @REM CUSTOMIZE: Change the list of certificates to create and their attributes.
   @REM Parameters to create_leaf: "file-name" "subject-name" "optional-subject-alternate-names"
   REM call :create_leaf server1 "/O=Org/CN=admn" "DNS:domino1.serv.org.com" || exit /B 1
   REM call :create_leaf server2 "/O=Org/CN=a" "DNS:domino2.serv.org.com" || exit /B 1
   call :create_leaf iamapp "/O=Org/CN=iamclientforproton" "DNS:auth.serv.org.com" || exit /B 1
   REM call :create_leaf finapp "/O=Org/OU=Apps/CN=finapp" "" || exit /B 1
   REM call :create_leaf salesapp "/O=Org/OU=Apps/CN=salesapp" "" || exit /B 1
   REM call :create_leaf hrapp "/O=Org/OU=Apps/CN=hrapp" "" || exit /B 1
   REM call :create_leaf storeapp "/O=OrgS/OU=Apps/CN=storeapp" "" || exit /B 1

   @REM Show details for certificates
   for /r %%v in (*.crt) do (call :show_cert %%v || exit /B 1)
   exit /B 0

   :show_cert
   echo on
   openssl x509 -in "%1" -text -noout -certopt no_pubkey,no_sigdump || exit /b 1
   @echo off
   exit /b 0

   :log
   echo.
   echo.
   echo %*
   pause
   exit /b 0

   @REM Creates CA cert and private key
   :create_root
   set LOG=CREATE_ROOT:
   if exist ca.key echo ca.key already exists, skipping&exit /B 0
   if exist ca.crt echo ca.crt already exists, skipping&exit /B 0

   ```
    call :log %LOG% Generate ROOT private key
    echo on
    openssl genrsa -passout "%ROOT_PASSWORD%" -des3 -out ca.key 4096 || exit /B 1
    @echo off

    call :log %LOG% Generate ROOT self-signed certificate
    echo on
    openssl req -passin "%ROOT_PASSWORD%" -new -x509 -days %ROOT_VALIDITY% -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj "%ROOT_SUBJECT%" -sha256 || exit /B 1
    @echo off

    exit /B 0
   ```

   @REM Creates certs using the CA and ca private key as signer
   @REM Three parameters:
   @REM Name - Name given to the certificate and private key file
   @REM Subject - Subject used in the certificate.
   @REM SANS - Subject Alternate Name which is domain name used for TLS host verification.
   :create_leaf
   set LOG=CREATE_LEAF:
   set NAME=%~1
   set SUBJ=%~2
   set SANS=%~3

   ```
    if exist %NAME%.key echo %NAME%.key already exists, skipping&exit /B 0
    if exist %NAME%.crt echo %NAME%.crt already exists, skipping&exit /B 0

    call :log %LOG% Generate %NAME%.key
    echo on
    openssl genrsa -passout "%LEAF_PASSWORD%" -des3 -out %NAME%.key 4096 || exit /B 1
    @echo off

    call :log %LOG% Generate Certificate Sign Request - CSR
    echo on
    openssl req -passin "%LEAF_PASSWORD%" -new -key %NAME%.key -out %NAME%.csr -subj "%SUBJ%" -sha256 || exit /B 1
    @echo off

    if "%SANS%" == "" (call :SIGN_NOSANS || exit /b 1) else (call :SIGN_WITHSANS || exit /b 1)

    call :log %LOG% Remove passphrase from Key
    echo on
    openssl rsa -passin "%LEAF_PASSWORD%" -in %NAME%.key -out %NAME%.key || exit /B 1
    @echo off

    call :log %LOG% Remove CSR
    del %NAME%.csr
    exit /B 0
   ```

   :SIGN_WITHSANS
   @REM Create a config file to pass the SAN extension
   call :log %LOG% Create signed certificate (WITHSANS)
   echo subjectAltName=%SANS% > %NAME%sans.cfg
   echo on
   openssl x509 -passin "%ROOT_PASSWORD%" -req -days %LEAF_VALIDITY% -in %NAME%.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -out %NAME%.crt -CAcreateserial -CAserial ca.seq -extfile %NAME%sans.cfg || exit /B 1
   @echo off
   del %NAME%sans.cfg
   exit /b 0

   :SIGN_NOSANS
   call :log %LOG% Create signed certificate (NOSANS)
   echo on
   openssl x509 -passin "%ROOT_PASSWORD%" -req -days %LEAF_VALIDITY% -in %NAME%.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -out %NAME%.crt -CAcreateserial -CAserial ca.seq || exit /B 1
   @echo off
   exit /b 0

[the result file of make_certs.cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkVG3.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think I need to ask you to open a ticket with support so we can go over each of these questions. I generally don't mind helping people on SO, but it bypasses our ability to see how many people use our product. There are also quite a few questions here and I want to make sure we get you working properly.

Can you open a support case?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot.  By using the verification scripts, the ca.crt with the following error C:\Certs>openssl s_client -connect serv.org.com:3003 --quiet -CAfile C:\Certs\ca.crt
depth=1 O = Org, CN = OrgCA
verify return:1
depth=0 O = Org, CN = proton-server
verify return:1
58150000:error:0A000126:SSL routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected eof while reading:ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:309: